# Firebird autoIncrement issue

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I've created Customers Table through following code :

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
ID INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
"NAME" VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8,
"LASTNAME" VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8);


ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);


SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE TRIGGER BI_CUSTOMERS_ID FOR CUSTOMERS
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT
POSITION 1
AS
BEGIN
 IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN
  NEW.ID = GEN_ID(CUSTOMERS_ID_GEN, 1);
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

But when I inserting second row like :

```
insert into Customers(Name,LastName) values('Hamed','Kamrava');
```

It gets below error :

```
Violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint "INTEG_2" on table "CUSTOMERS".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` is a primary key with default value `1`.

In the first record, since you have not explicitly mentioned the value of `id`, it has inserted with 1. But you cannot have any other records with `id = 1` since `id` is a Primary Key.

Use the statement:

```
insert into Customers(id, Name, LastName) values (2, 'Hamed', 'Kamrava');
```

This should insert the record. If you do not want to hardcode the value of ID for each row, suggest you to [create a `sequence`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/sql-createsequence.html) and then during the insert, use,

```
insert into Customers(id, Name, LastName) values (nextval('<seq_name>'), <name>, <lastname>);
```

Comment: tnx. But a generator already existed. <br/> `CREATE GENERATOR CUSTOMERS_ID_GEN;

SET GENERATOR CUSTOMERS_ID_GEN TO 1;`

Comment: @HamedKamrava But you are not adding that to the insert.

Answer (score 4):

Since your trigger code is

```
 IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN
  NEW.ID = GEN_ID(CUSTOMERS_ID_GEN, 1);
```

and, as @Orangecrush posted, you set a default value of 1, a unique id is never generated. So you should try to omit the default value in the ddl.